# Model Validations Failing with FactoryGirl Rspec, Validations Seems To Be Ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec

I am having an issue with my Rails Model validation tests. The validation is functioning properly (it rejects incorrectly formatted emails) but the tests are failing.

Here is my important information from my user.rb model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :address, :city, :state, :zip_code, :phone_home, :phone_cell, :phone_work, :status_id, :password_confirmation, :is_test, :parent_paramed_id, :company, :logo, :is_agent, :is_paramed, :additional_emails

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validate :validates_single_email_format
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email

  def validates_single_email_format
    User.validates_single_email_format(self.email)
  end

  def self.validates_single_email_format(email)
    email =~ VALID_EMAIL_REGEX
  end
```

Here is my user_spec.rb

```
describe User do
  context "validate email address on create" do
    before { User.delete_all }

    context "fails" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.build(:user, :email => 'blah') }
      before { user.save; binding.pry }
      specify { user.should_not be_valid }
    end

    context "succeeds" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.build(:user, :email => 'matt@google.com' ) }
      before { user.save; binding.pry }
      specify { user.should be_valid }
    end

  end
end
```

This is the output of this test as it is executed with a binding.pry after each save to see what the user object looks like after save is called:

```
From: /project/spec/models/user_spec.rb @ line 96 :

     91:   context "validate email address on create" do
     92:     before { User.delete_all }
     93:
     94:     context "fails" do
     95:       let(:user) { FactoryGirl.build(:user, :email => 'blah') }
 =>  96:       before { user.save; binding.pry }
     97:       specify { user.should_not be_valid }
     98:     end
     99:
    100:     context "succeeds" do
    101:       let(:user) { FactoryGirl.build(:user, :email => 'matt@google.com' ) }

[1] pry(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_4::Nested_1>)> user
=> #<User id: 178, first_name: "Martha", middle_name: nil, last_name: "Magdalena", email: "blah", additional_emails: nil, password_hash: "$2a$10$HF1t3cIwQiwj7PN/DkBgwOJw667FFixFB3srksZypHxR...", password_salt: "$2a$10$HF1t3cIwQiwj7PN/DkBgwO", password_reset_token: nil, password_reset_sent_at: nil, address: nil, city: nil, state: nil, zip_code: nil, phone_home: nil, phone_cell: nil, phone_work: nil, status_id: 1, is_test: false, parent_paramed_id: nil, company: nil, logo: nil, is_agent: true, is_paramed: false, created_at: "2013-04-20 18:13:02", updated_at: "2013-04-20 18:13:02">
[2] pry(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_4::Nested_1>)> exit
F
From: /project/spec/models/user_spec.rb @ line 102 :

     97:       specify { user.should_not be_valid }
     98:     end
     99:
    100:     context "succeeds" do
    101:       let(:user) { FactoryGirl.build(:user, :email => 'matt@google.com' ) }
 => 102:       before { user.save; binding.pry }
    103:       specify { user.should be_valid }
    104:     end
    105:
    106:   end
    107:

[1] pry(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_4::Nested_2>)> user
=> #<User id: 179, first_name: "Martha", middle_name: nil, last_name: "Magdalena", email: "matt@google.com", additional_emails: nil, password_hash: "$2a$10$LEA28MGLIdLuk6lPEPGmH.lW3QwkR9KoXgbULPHJZa4v...", password_salt: "$2a$10$LEA28MGLIdLuk6lPEPGmH.", password_reset_token: nil, password_reset_sent_at: nil, address: nil, city: nil, state: nil, zip_code: nil, phone_home: nil, phone_cell: nil, phone_work: nil, status_id: 1, is_test: false, parent_paramed_id: nil, company: nil, logo: nil, is_agent: true, is_paramed: false, created_at: "2013-04-20 18:13:11", updated_at: "2013-04-20 18:13:11">
[2] pry(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_4::Nested_2>)> exit
.

Failures:

  1) User validate email address on create fails
     Failure/Error: specify { user.should_not be_valid }
       expected valid? to return false, got true
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:97:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 16.9 seconds
2 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:97 # User validate email address on create fails
```

For some reason the test that fails is returning true even though it sees the email value as "blah." If I run the validation method on the object it responds by saying there is no match. But for some reason the "expected valid?" test is returning true. I am not sure why this is occurring.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I could find any similar enough questions in the existing questions.

EDIT: Removed computer specific information in the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things. Your `validates_single_email_format` method does not only need to return `false`, it has to call `errors.add(:email, "Email is in wrong format!")` to be have some effect.

The `valid?` method does not just run validations, it also adds the error messages to `errors` and `errors` is empty in the end, then the model is considered valid.

Anyway, you could use:

```
validates_format_of :email, with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of validation is incorrect. Try this correct one in just two lines.

```
EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true, format: {with: EMAIL_REGEX}
```

Comment: I actually had your code when I first started. 

I should have mentioned that we were making the instance method so we could use the method in other ways and for other places that we use email. The solution I posted about (albeit incorrect in that state) was more modular and could be used more widely. 

Thanks for adding this though!